# Complex no. problem (involving Euler's identity)

Tags: complex-numbers

Here's the problem:
$$
e^{2 m i \cot ^{-1} p \cdot\left(\frac{p i+1}{p i-1}\right)^{m}}=
$$

I got this from internet. I tried substituting $p=\cot(∆/2)$, managed to solve a bit of the problem but couldn't do it further.

Note: There isn't any remark about the domain of "$m$" and "$p$" in the question.

Comment: Is it supposed to be $\pi$ and not "p times iota"?

Comment: I don't know. Well, maybe... I'll try solving it though. However, it is very unlikely though

Comment: No.. It still ain't coming

Comment: @P.Patil Are you simply seeking a simplification of the above expression?

Comment: I am very sorry... I think the question has some error.